# Git GitHub Synching set-up

Tags: git, github

My company and I are looking for a new versioning set-up:

- We would like to use git
- We allready have a github organization account, and several projects on github
- What we would like to accomplish:

> A central git server running on our own machine. This is the server where we push our local changes to. This server is in sync with GitHub, so all the projects that are pushed to the central server are automatically stored on GitHub with the correct users.
>
> **local** <--> **git server** <---> **github**

Does anyone have a decent set-up / workflow example for this kind of versioning?

Comment: Why would you need to have your repository hosted on a central server **and** on Github

Comment: Because GitHub comes with a delay, which has given us a hard-time on some occasions. Mostly this delay occured when people were working on different Operating Systems. So we would like a versioning system to develop locally without the delay, but also keep everyhting in the cloud.

Comment: Another reasing for doing this is because we don't want to be solely dependant on our internet connection or otherwise on GitHub. This way we can benefit of the local repository when the internet or GitHub is down, and we can benefit from the cloud storage that GitHub provides.

Comment: That's a fair point. Still, on the face of it (from my perspective), it seems a bit odd to use a local server and Github

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your workflow, if you want to manage the git repositories internally a really good piece of software is called [Gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq), it's pretty much Github on your own server (and unlike Github Enterprise, it's free and open-source).

Next, I suppose you could use a continuous integration system that can run tests on your code and push it up to Github automatically, such as [Gilab CI](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci).